# How to Import Swift Source Code into a XCode Swift Project

Tags: xcode, swift3

I've written a working swift prototype. It contains a parent class and some subclasses. I want to be able to import the parent class into another project where I will create sub classes for it.

I created a new XCode project for a dynamic library, added the parent class to it and ran build. I've seen where you can't use static for Swift code.

I also created a different directory and set up a swift package. The build on it ran successfully.

When I add an import statement to the project where I want to use it, it says it can't find it. The statement is: "import RailsData", the name of the parent class.

I've tried adding the dynamic library project to "Linked Frameworks and Libraries". I also tried adding the swift file directly. XCode flags the import as not found.

The swift package manager example is all command line based so I'm not sure if will work with XCode projects. I would eventually like to make a package out of it.

Xcode 8.2, Swift 3.0. I'm pretty sure I'm missing something fundamental.

## Update

I found a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39708845/adding-swift-3-packages-to-xcode-8-using-the-swift-package-manager). It says to

> Put your package manifest file into the same directory as the Xcode project, and then invoke swift package generate-xcodeproj

With a search I found [this page](https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager/blob/master/Documentation/Reference.md#package-manifest-file-format-reference) that says:

> Instructions for how to build a package are provided by the Package.swift manifest file.

So I copied the file to the root of my project and ran the command above. It created a new .xcodeproj. When I opened it, I saw my original files, but not anything from the package. That's not surprising as there is no reference to it's location in the file system. Also a mystery is what happens when you want additional packages. Do you keep generating new projects?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the missing link is the following command

```
swift package generate-xcodeproj
```

Actually [Adding Swift 3 packages to Xcode 8 using the Swift package manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39708845/adding-swift-3-packages-to-xcode-8-using-the-swift-package-manager) should answer your question.

Comment: I saw that question right after I posted this one. I copied the Manifest file(aka Package.swift to the root directory of my project and ran "swift package generate-xcodeproj". I generate a new project and pulled in the files from my current one. Since I only copied in the Package.switf, it didn't add the contents of the package.